# Region on specific page

Tags: theming

Is it possible to set a region on a specific page? I've created a page and I only want it to display it there and not elsewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create View Block.

Go to **Home » Administration » Structure » View**

**Add New View.**

**Create a Block** with View (**Not** Create a Page)

[image: Block with View]

Then, Select that block on the specific page.

If you have created that page with Panels or Node Template (By Adding New Variant)
You can set View Rule.

- Add Visibility Rule in View Block

[image: Select Visibility Rule in View]

Select **String: URL Path** as an Option

Then, set path to your page where you wanted to display your block.

[image: Set String URL Path]

I hope this will help you..

Answer (score 0):

You can use blocks and specify a specific page for it to display content.

Comment: Yes, indeed but in page.tpl.php I've added some text that belongs to that region. I see the text on every page now.

Comment: Move that text to a block and change the show on pages only attribute to include the page you desire.  Use css to customize the text layout.

Answer (score -1):

You can restrict the display of the blocks to pages, content types, roles, languages.